# Get short hash using github api

Tags: github-api

I want to get the short hash/sha of a GitHub commit, is there a way to get the short hash using GitHub API?
I was not able to find out anything on the official documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

This trick did it for me:

`curl -s -L https://api.github.com/repos/:ORG/:REPO/git/refs/heads/master | grep sha | cut -d '"' -f 4 | cut -c 1-7`